# Getting bad request response When sending data to server using SIM900

Tags: http, gsm, sim900

```
AT+CSTT="live.vodafone.com"$0D$0A                       OK

AT+CIPSHUT$0D$0A                                        SHUT OK

AT+CIPMUX=0$0D$0A                                       OK

AT+CLPORT="TCP",80$0D$0A                                OK

AT+CIICR$0D$0A                                          OK

AT+CIPSTART="TCP","http://ph.mydomain.in",80$0D$0A      OK   CONNECT OK

AT+CIPSEND$0D$0A                                        

GET /phreading.aspx?value=092016040804550815 HTTP/1.1$0D$0A
Host: http://www.ph.mydomain.in$0D$0A$0D$0A
$1A
```

than i get following error.

[image]
Please help me to solve this problem. and tell me the right sequence to send data on server correctly.

Comment: are you using http://www.ph.mydomain.in as the domain? If so it is not a valid hostname

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `AT+HTTPPARA` command to send your get request. Its much easier than using the `CIPSEND` method.

**Connect to GPRS**

```
AT+CGATT?
AT+SAPBR=3,1,"CONTYPE","GPRS"
AT+SAPBR=3,1,"APN","live.vodafone.com"
AT+SAPBR=3,1,"USER","APN_USERNAME"  // adapt it to yours
AT+SAPBR=3,1,"PWD","APN_PASSWORD" // adapt it to yours
AT+SAPBR=1,1
```

**SEND DATA USING HTTP GET**

```
AT+HTTPINIT
AT+HTTPPARA="CID",1
AT+HTTPPARA="URL","www.ph.mydomain.in//phreading.aspx?value=092016040804550815"
AT+HTTPACTION=0 // sends HTTP GET  
AT+HTTPTERM  // terminate HTTP request
AT+SAPBR=0,1 // disconnect gprs if required
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: Thank you so much. Great it work for me. and what is the procedure to send same data using POST method.

Comment: you can +1 the answer if its helpful